# How to make an optional variable in angular expression?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**Example:**

```
var scope = {
      thing: 'Monkey'
    };
$interpolate("Awesome{{' ' + thing}}!")(scope);
                       ^^^
```

I don't want to print a white space when `thing` is null or undefined.

**Expectectations:**

1. scope.thing == 'Monkey'

   -> "Awesome Monkey!"
2. scope.thing == null

   -> "Awesome!"

Is it possible to specify `{{' ' + thing}}` somehow to not print anything when `thing` is null or undefined?

**EDIT:**

Possible I need something like this `{{ thing && (' ' + thing) }}`, but I guess that with angular it should be possible to be done in more elegant way.

*PS I'm new in Angular, so sometimes I develop a wheel :)*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Great answers.
It's not that much logic but you could put it into the controller. For better separation and testability.

Just create a function like this in the controller:

```
$scope.thingOrNothing = function(){
  return !$scope.model.thing || ' ' + $scope.model.thing + ' ';
}
```

And in html, call the function like this:

```
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <p>Hello{{thingOrNothing()}}Men!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: This is a good idea! I can use thingOrNothing() as a wrapper and send data as argument, for example `Hello{{thingOrNothing(thing)}}Men!`.

Comment: Yes, exactly like MajoB does it with his $scope.print function. We wrote our answers at the same time :-)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: first time i misunderstood the question. Now it should be ok.

```
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.model = {
      thing: 'Monkey',
      emptyThing: null
  };

  $scope.print = function (value) {
      if (value)
      {
         return ' ' + value;
      }
      return '';
    };
});

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello{{print(model.thing)}}!</p>
    <p>Hello{{print(model.emptyThing)}}!</p>
  </body>
```

You can create a filter if yo want to reuse this functionality across multiple controllers:

```
app.filter('addWhitespace', function() {
    return function(input) {
     if (input)
      {
         return ' ' + input;
      }
      return '';
    };
});

<p>Hello{{model.thing | addWhitespace}}!</p>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/J9PKfhNC1SzKZKw7Z5yl?p=preview

Tip #2:
Do not replace the entire scope with your custom object create a new property on the scope instead.

Comment: I like the idea about `print()` that is used as a wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to go with IIf notation:

```
$interpolate("Awesome{{thing ? ' ' + thing : ''}}!")(scope);
```